# What part of a JWT token is unique to the user and doesn't change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I have an API made in Rails where people can only make a request to it, if they send along a JWT token - https://jwt.io. I'm using Rack::Attack to rate limit people based on IP. Now I also want to rate limit people based on the request token they send along.

Which of the 3 parts of the JWT token below is unique to that user? Does that part change from time to time? In other words... which part can I identify the user on?

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No part of the JWT will ever be unique for a user 100% of the time.

- HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE  - Is not unique to the user
- PAYLOAD:DATA - expiration is part of the payload which changes with every token that's issued
- VERIFY SIGNATURE - signature verification is based on the payload which changes

The best bet is to decode the token and use part of the data stored in the token that identifies the user and is immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That clarifies things. I'll decode the token and use the "sub" attribute.